# SELECT TOP (x amount of rows) videos watched by a single user

Tags: sql, select

I am writing an SQL Query to return the top X number of rows of most re-watched videos by a single user.

So for example the output should resemble this:

```
Mike, cat video, 16 views
John, dog video, 13 views
John, snake video, 10 views
Mike, snake video, 8 views
```

What I have is:

```
SELECT TOP (X)
user, video_title, view_count
FROM STREAMED_VIDEOS
WHERE = 
ORDER BY view_count (DESC)
```

I am not looking for the answer but a nudge in the right direction. What command/clause should I look into to figure this out? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You say "by a single user" but your example output lists two different users.    Please clarify whether you want results for a single user, or all users.  Perhaps it would be better if you give some sample rows in your SOURCE first.

Comment: if you remove the `WHERE = ` I think you will get the result you want

Comment: Richard, it goes by the number of views a single user has rewatched a particular video. In this case Mike has watched the cat video 16 times. The next most rewatched video was the dog video which was rewatcheed by John a total 13 times. The snake video was most rewatched by John 10 times and then by Mike 8 times. Let me know if you need more clarification. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

You could have look at the window functions ROW_NUMBER and DENSE_RANK.

They calculate an increasing number, which can be based on a PARTITION (similar to a GROUP BY) and an ORDER BY.

Once that number is calculated, you can filter on it.

```
SELECT sv.user, video_title, view_count
FROM
(
    SELECT 
     t.user, video_title, view_count,
     DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY user ORDER BY view_count DESC) AS Rnk
    FROM STREAMED_VIDEOS t
) sv
WHERE Rnk = 2 -- put X here
ORDER BY view_count DESC
```